# Equal elementary symmetric polynomials implies existence of permutation

Tags: symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

The origin of the question is from Chapter 1, Problem 6.9 in *Theory of Point Estimation* by Lehmann.

Let $e_k(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ denote the k-th [elementary polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). Consider two tuples $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and $(y_1, ..., y_n)$. If we have $e_k(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = e_k(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$, then this implies that the $y$'s are a permutation of the $x$'s.

I was wondering if anyone had a reference (or a hint) to this result. My original idea was to use induction on the number of variables; however, it was not clear to me on how to reduce the induction step and use the induction assumption in a meaningful way that would yield the desired result.

Comment: Do you know how the elementary polynomials relate the roots of a polynomial to its coefficients?

Comment: Look under "Properties" on the Wikipedia page you cite.  The monic polynomial in $\lambda$ for the $x_i$ is the same as that for the $y_i$, and the set  $\{x_i\}$ is the root set of that polynomial, as is the set $\{y_i\}$...

Comment: @kimchilover Ah, I missed that! That makes perfect sense to me then. Much appreciated!